# How to deploy a desktop application that includes a neural network?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I have developed a desktop application. It includes a neural network as a part of the application. Now I'm confused what to do after training. Can I make an executable out of it as usual method?

Please someone explain what should do, because I have no idea how to pass this milestone. I've tried searching neural network tutorials. But none of them helped me with this problem.

If someone wants to know, I have used numpy and openCV only.

Comment: Are you wanting to distribute the application with the *trained* network? Will the end user perform more training on their machine?

Comment: @NeilSlater No, they will not train. I will be doing all the training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neural network weights are just data. You can store this any way you like along with the distributed application. As you have used Numpy to create the weights and biases array, you can probably just use `pickle` - add `save_network` function or similar name (used in training program only) and `load_network` function. If your weights and biases are just a bunch of local variables, you will want put them into a structure like a `dict` first.

Comment: when training like this are the weights stored separately in another location? Do you know material to refer? So I can use it when I'm training

Comment: @joe When you start training you won't have any stored weights at all. Just save them when done. Where to find them in the distributed package is a different issue - it will depend on how you are packaging the app. But it is no different from finding any other resource file - e.g. an image to display, or a default config file. It has nothing to do with neural networks. What are you using to package your application?

Comment: What do you mean by "What are you using to package your application?"  ?

Comment: How are you getting your application code (a set of different .py files and possibly other resources) installed on another machine ready to use? For example, will your users be running `pip install`, or are you packaging this up into something like a Windows .msi, Mac OS .dmg, or a Linux .pkg? You mention creating an executable - are you using a specific tool to create a stand-alone executable file from your code?

Comment: At present user has to run pip install for other packages.

Comment: So I guess they just have a copy of your development files? Therefore, add the weights file in that structure too (if this is distributed via git repo, simplest is to add the weights file there), and refer it by name it relative to the .py file that needs to load it. Alternatively you can host the weights file somewhere on the internet and fetch it on-demand. This is a common approach in larger libraries for downloading e.g. MNIST digits data, or the VGG-19 pre-trained neural network.